# Using and IF/AND Excel Statement with MID Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to compare the first character in two different cells. If they both equal 9 than I want it to say TRUE, otherwise false.

I have the most terrible version of that written below. Can someone help me write this correctly?

```
=IF(AND(MID(B2,1,1))="9",(MID(C2,1,1))="9",TRUE,FALSE))
```

B2 and C2 are zip codes. I just want to see if they start with a 9 which shows they're in the same area but the exact cells don't match so I can't do a straight comparison of the entire cell. i.e. 94021 and 94111 would be TRUE since they both start with 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
=IF(AND(LEFT(A1,1)="9", LEFT(B1,1)="9"), TRUE,FALSE)
```

No need to use `MID`, `LEFT`will give you N first characters. Also `AND` combines logical conditions you can pass to `IF`

Comment: Note that you don't need the `IF` at all, since `AND` returns TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: @DougGlancy Yup thanks. Kept the above more universal in case a custom text is needed as a result

Comment: Hmmm, this is saying "true" when it shouldn't. Any ideas?
i.e. A1=94131 B1=54923 - The cells are formatted as text 
(it was removing the zeros of zip-codes that started with 0 when formatted as a number)

Comment: Are u sure you point the function to correct cells? What's the data look like?

Comment: Yes the function is on the correct cells :) Could it be due to the formating?

A1=94601 B1=01929 - it is returning a true with the formula above

Comment: The function should implicitly convert numbers to text, but just in case try explicit conversion: `=IF(AND(LEFT(TEXT(A1,"00000"),1)="9", LEFT(TEXT(B1,"00000"),1)="9"), TRUE,FALSE)`

Comment: No problem :) Glad the solution was helpful

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
=IF(left(B2,1) = Left(C2,1))
```

Comment: Unfortunately the B2 and C2 are zip codes. I just want to see if they start with a 9 which shows they're in the same area but the exact cells won't match

Comment: The way I read the [LEFT function](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/left-leftb-functions-HP010342648.aspx) this should work.  It should only pull the first character from each cell.  If the zip are stored as numbers, you may need to TEXT() first.